# Problemas de hardware con ubuntu con windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows10

instale ubuntu desde microsoft store e iba todo bien, pero al siguiente dia cuando quice prender mi equipo la pantalla parpadeaba y dejaba de dar imagen, intente deshabilitar el hardware de la pantalla y aun asi seguia el problema, mi solucion fue desabilitar la virtualizacion y linux en W10 y reiniciar, pero me pregunto si existe otra solucion que no sea dualbot?
Se me olvido comentar y no se si tenga algo que ver pero quice instalar ohmyzsh, no si se tenga algo que ver

desinstalar ubuntu y la maquina virtual de windows

Comment: Revisa si hay un archivo config antiguo para X en /etc.  Si hay, puede reemplacar el nuevo con el antiguo, y es posible que funcione.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es sobre programación. [su] sería [más adecuada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57999/1065142) o [ubuntu.se].